# Users can only save their draft once before saving for revision

Tags: user-roles, capabilities, draft, revisions, customization

I use the [Members](https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/) Plugin and Custom Post Types.

I created a role and want them to contribute posts (within this Custom Post Type `musician`) but don't publish them. Additionally I want to give the possibility to save drafts.

My role has (among others) the following capabilities:

- `edit_musician`
- `edit_musicians` (plural, really necessary?)

Now people can create posts, see only their own posts and can save for review. They can also save their posts as a draft, but only once! After the first save, they can only save for review. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I do not know the answer to your true question (why save draft only works once), but can address your confusion about edit_musician and edit_musicians.  First, I would direct you to [this post by Justin Tadlock](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/07/10/meta-capabilities-for-custom-post-types), the author of Members, as it does a good job of explaining meta capabilities and how they map.  Long answer short, if you decide the meta caps are appropriate, the plural is the one you want, but you also need to enable 'map_meta_cap' on your CPT. Can you show your `register_post_type` code?

Comment: This was my abridged [code](http://pastebin.com/RNRuzWw1). Now I adapted the mapping described in the blog post and it works :-)